# Refer to another table and return data adjacent to Max() result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I have the following two tables:

[image: Data tables]

Using `SQL Server 2012`, I want to know the `INTERVAL` from the Hourly table where the `MaxWaitTime` and `Split` match what comes from the `Daily` table for each day. I am assuming I need to use a `window function` here, but I can't figure out the right answer.

[image: Expected Result]

There may be times where `MaxWaitTime` is `0` for an entire day, and thus all rows from the `hourly` table match. In this scenario, I would prefer a `Null` answer, but the earliest `INTERVAL` for that day would be fine.

There will also be times where multiple `INTERVALs` have the same wait time. In this scenario the first `INTERVAL` where the `MaxWaitTime` is present that day should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` if you want at most one match:

Looks like a simple left join should work between the tables. I'm simply going by the data shown above...

The query should look something like this. If the join fails, then a NULL will be returned. Give it a go..

```
select d.*, h.interval as maxinterval
from daily d outer apply
     (select top 1 h.*
      from hourly h
      where convert(date, h.interval) = d.row_date and
            h.split = d.split and
            h.maxwaittime = d.maxwaittime
      order by h.interval asc
     ) h;
```

If you want `NULL` for multiple matches, you can do something similar:

```
select d.*, h.interval as maxinterval
from daily d outer apply
     (select top 1 h.callsoffered, h.split, max(h.interval) as maxinterval
      from hourly h
      where convert(date, h.interval) = d.row_date and
            h.split = d.split and
            h.maxwaittime = d.maxwaittime
      group by h.maxwaittime, h.split
      having count(*) = 1
     ) h;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple left join should work between the tables. I'm simply going by the data shown above...

The query should look something like this. If the join fails, then a NULL will be returned. Give it a go..

```
select daily.* ,hourly.callsoffered, hourly.interval as maxinterval

from daily

left join hourly 
   on convert(date,hourly.interval) = daily.row_date
     and hourly.split = daily.split
     and hourly.maxwaittime = daily.maxwaittime
```

Comment: Harry, thanks for your reply. I also thought the left join would do it initially, but this solution fails given the conditions stated above - when multiple rows match I get multiple results for the same day. The tables above are really just illustrations.

Comment: can you supply actual data then please? The illustration data suggests that the above query should work..  what is being repeated? Looks like other than the Interval, all the data is available in the Daily Table.. so I just don't see how the data is being duplicated. Unless you have identical max wait times for different intervals..